# How to edit two different models in one form

Tags: django, forms, models

I have two models. In first you can create name of product and write a price. Second model is a cart which contains these products.

Now I want create a form where user can propose cost of products in cart which I will make.
For example I created cart1 which contains product1 and product2. I want give possibility to edit this price in cart form.

How can I do it? Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}({})".format(self.name, self.price)

class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class CartForm(forms.ModelForm):
        product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),required=True) 
        name = forms.CharField(max_length=45, label='nazwa')
        price = forms.IntegerField(label='price')


        class Meta: 
                model = Cart
                fields = ('product', 'name', 'price')
```

Here is photo what I have and what I want (now i have one price - to all products, I want one price for one product):

[image]

Second problem: now I have checkbox, how can I do that there is no checkbox or list but everything must be automatically choose (user must choose all products from this cart).

EDIT:
Now i have this:

```
    class CartForm(forms.ModelForm):
            product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),required=True) 
            name = forms.CharField(max_length=45, label='nazwa')
            price = forms.IntegerField(label='price')


            class Meta: 
                    model = Cart
                    fields = ('product', 'name', 'price')

    IngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Cart, Product)
```

views.py:

```
def cart_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CartForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cart = form.save(commit=False)
            cart.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            ingredient_formset = IngredientFormSet(request.POST)
            if ingredient_formset.is_valid():
                ingredient = formset.save(commit=False)
                ingredient_formset.save()
                return redirect('shop.views.cart_detail', pk=cart.pk)
    else:
        form = CartForm()
    return render(request, 'shop/cart_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [InlineFormSetView](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html#inlineformsetview) provided by [Django Extra Views](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Here is an example copied from the doc:

```
from extra_views import InlineFormSetView


class EditProductReviewsView(InlineFormSetView):
    model = Product
    inline_model = Review

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need an formset for your sub-model (product). Then in your view you should access both: form for main model and formset for submodel and save it. An example of forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

# ... import here your models

class CartForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta: 
            model = Cart
            fields = ('product', 'name', 'price')

IngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Cart, Product)
```

And then use it in your view.

Comment: Hi thank you! I tried to do like you said - you can check it, I added views file. But i get error. "Cart has no ForeignKey to Product". I did this way first time and now i have no idea how to edit this again.